# intellij cannot resolve symbol "File"

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I have this in my script

```
import groovy.io.FileType
.....
derp = new File("blah")
```

The script works but inetillij complains it cant resolve "File" and it suggested I import a totally different wrong library for it (com.jidesoft.icons.IconSet)

I already tried invalidating cache and restarting

How do I get intelllij to import  groovy.io.FileType? I cant even find a way to suppress error either it doesnt give me that option

Comment: Is it possible to provide full sample code example?

Answer (score 1):

`groovy.io.FileType` is an enum class. It appears your variable `derp` would be of type `File`, not `FileType`.

You can statically import enums from the FileType class (for example):

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.*
```

In my Intellij on Java 8 the `File` class comes from the `java.io` package in a .groovy file.